# Passing Secret Value to DocumentDB

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, aws-secrets-manager

I'm creating a secret and passing it as a user password to AWS DocumentDB with Python CDK but i keep getting Could not parse SecretString JSON error.

```
        excluded_characters = "!@#$%^&*()`~,}{[]_=+'?\/|<>:;-" + '"'

        generated_database_password = secretsmanager.Secret(
            self,
            "DatabasePassword",
            generate_secret_string=secretsmanager.SecretStringGenerator(
                password_length=8,
                exclude_characters=excluded_characters,
                exclude_punctuation=True,
            ),
        )

        # Creating secret manager to store database environment variables
        cluster_secret_manager = secretsmanager.Secret(
            self,
            "DbSecrets",
            secret_name="db_secret",
            secret_object_value={
                "db_admin": SecretValue.unsafe_plain_text("admin"),
                "db_pw": generated_database_password.secret_value,
            },
        )

        vpc = ec2.Vpc.from_lookup(self, "VPCLookup", vpc_id=props.vpc_id)
        application_subnet = vpc.select_subnets(
            subnet_group_name="application"
        ).subnet_ids

        cluster = docdbelastic.CfnCluster(
            self,
            "MongoDbCluster",
            admin_user_name=f"{props.customer}",
            auth_type="PLAIN_TEXT",
            cluster_name=f"{props.customer}-mongodb-cluster",
            shard_capacity=2,
            shard_count=4,
            admin_user_password=generated_database_password.secret_value_from_json("database_password").unsafe_unwrap(),
            subnet_ids=application_subnet,
        )
```

how do i convert the value to str? or am i using the wrong method?

Comment: Can you share the full error? ... have you tried to output just `generated_database_password.secret_value_from_json("database_password")...` see what that gives you

Comment: Could not parse SecretString JSON erro is the full error

Comment: Where does this error appear?

Answer (score 1):

Your `generated_database_password` secret does not have a JSON field named `database_password`, it is a simple string secret. You can simply do:

```
admin_user_password=generated_database_password.secret_value.unsafe_unwrap()
```

I'm not sure why you're creating two separate Secrets Manager secrets, though.

Comment: Isn't it unsafe to directly pass the secret as plain text? What's the point of creating a secret in this case? There is some other method where the authType is `SECRET_ARN` but I am unable a find a way to use it - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77913670/how-to-pass-aws-secret-to-elastic-document-db-cluster-using-cdk-terraform-clou

Comment: It is unsafe to pass the reference into places where it's kept as plaintext. A database password is not one of those cases - the value will not appear in plaintext anywhere. To clarify - it will be passed as a reference.

Comment: Does `unsafe_unravel()` directly return the secret string like "1cargsecretString"? Or do we need to again call to_string() on top of it?

Comment: It's `unsafe_unwrap`. No - like I said, it will be passed as a reference, the actual plaintext value will not be in the template.