# How to pass AWS Secret to Elastic Document DB Cluster using CDK/ Terraform/ Cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk, aws-documentdb

I am trying to create a **Elastic** Document DB cluster using AWS CDK. This is the [L1 resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_docdbelastic.CfnCluster.html) to achieve the same (sadly there is no L2 construct for **Elastic** doc db).

There is a property `authType` which accepts either `PLAIN_TEXT` or `SECRET_ARN` as values. The documentation doesn't clarify what it means. Neither is the [Cloudformation documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-docdbelastic-cluster.html) clear. I am assuming that when the value is set to `PLAIN_TEXT`, we have to hardcode our password in our CDK code under the `adminUserPassword` field (which is not secure). So how to use the `SECRET_ARN` value? Where do I create and pass my AWS Secret?

The CDK documentation states that `adminUserPassword` is an optional field while the Cloud formation documentation states that it is a conditional field. But when I omit this field (regardless of the value of authType), Cloudformation throws an error that this field is missing.

This is what I tried

```
const secret = new cdk.aws_secretsmanager.Secret(this, 'DocDbSecret', {
      description: "Secret for docDb cluster",
      secretName: "docDbSecret", 
    });


    const elasticCluster = new aws_docdbelastic.CfnCluster(this, 'elasticCluster', {
        adminUserName: 'myAdmin',
        adminUserPassword: secret.secretArn, // Should we pass secret here? if yes how?
        authType: 'SECRET_ARN',
        clusterName: 'myCluster',
        shardCapacity: 2,
        shardCount: 2,
    });
```

The [terraform resource](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/docdbelastic_cluster#admin_user_password) also has the same confusion...

Comment: I'm not sure I'm reading this the right way, but it could be [Secrets Manager is not yet supported](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/docdb-using-elastic-clusters.html#elastic-admin-diagnostics-limitations).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have to pass the ARN of the secret in the `adminUserPassword` field.

Though, the password for doc db cluster has some conditions which should be specified when generating the secret.

- Auth type will be `SECRET_ARN`.
- adminUserPassword will be `secret.secretArn`
- Secret

should not contain `@"/`

```js
/**
 * Create a new secret
 * https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_secretsmanager.Secret.html
 */
const secret = new secretsmanager.Secret(this, 'docDbSecret', {
  description: "Description",
  secretName: "docDbSecret",
  generateSecretString: {
    // Don't include / @ "
    excludeCharacters: '/@"',
  }
});


const elasticCluster = new aws_docdbelastic.CfnCluster(this, 'elasticCluster', {
    adminUserName: 'myAdmin',
    adminUserPassword: secret.secretArn, 
    authType: 'SECRET_ARN',
    clusterName: 'myCluster',
    shardCapacity: 2,
    shardCount: 2,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the L2 `opensearch.Domain`? Then you can specify the engine to be elastic: `opensearch.EngineVersion.ELASTICSEARCH_7_10`.

But to answer your question exactly, you need to tell CDK to parse the secret value as a string.

```
        
secret = secretmanager.Secret(
    scope=self,
    id="Secret",
    generate_secret_string=secretmanager.SecretStringGenerator(
        generate_string_key="password",
        password_length=30,
        secret_string_template="{\"username\":\"myAdmin\"}",
        exclude_characters="%+~`#$&*()|[]{}:;<>?!'/@\"",
    )
)

docdb.CfnCluster(
    scope=self,
    id="DocDB",
    admin_user_name=secret.secret_value_from_json("username").to_string(),
    admin_user_password=secret.secret_value_from_json("password").to_string(),
    auth_type="PLAINTEXT",
    cluster_name="docdb-cluster",
    shard_capacity=1,
    shard_count=1,
)
```

Will result in this:

```
"StorageDocDBD4AB00F5": {
   "Type": "AWS::DocDBElastic::Cluster",
   "Properties": {
    "AdminUserName": {
     "Fn::Join": [
      "",
      [
       "{{resolve:secretsmanager:",
       {
        "Ref": "StorageSecretAF41D9AB"
       },
       ":SecretString:username::}}"
      ]
     ]
    },
    "AdminUserPassword": {
     "Fn::Join": [
      "",
      [
       "{{resolve:secretsmanager:",
       {
        "Ref": "StorageSecretAF41D9AB"
       },
       ":SecretString:password::}}"
      ]
     ]
    },
    "AuthType": "PLAINTEXT",
    "ClusterName": "docdb-cluster",
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can create a username / password in AWS Secrets Manager, with the username being the name of your secret.
You can then reference this ARN in the call.
[image: secret-ARN]

Comment: I don't think that's an issue, since the code in the OP shows the secret is being created.